# How to get the polly circuit breaker state without executing the requests

Tags: c#, .net-core, dotnet-httpclient, polly, circuit-breaker

I understand that we can use the circuit state to fetch the current state with in the context. but is there a way that I can get the circuit state outside the context. for eg in below here If I want to get the circuit state at the controller how do I do that? right now I set up a static variable in the policy but when the circuit is broken it's context is not available to fetch. Here is my current setup.

Startup

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
    services.AddHttpClient<IIntCall, IntCall>().WrapResilientPolicies();
}
```

Interface

```
public interface IIntCall
    {
        Task<bool> DoSomething();
    }
```

Implementation:

```
public class IntCall : IIntCall
    {
private readonly HttpClient client;

public IntCall(HttpClient httpClient)
{
    this.client = httpClient;
}

public async Task<bool> DoSomething()
{
    var response = await client.GetAsync("http://www.onegoogle.com");
    var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    return false;
}
}
```

Polly Implementation

```
public static class CBExtensions
    {
    public static void WrapResilientPolicies(this IHttpClientBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.AddPolicyHandler((service, request) =>
        GetRetryPolicy().WrapAsync(GetCircuitBreakerPolicy()));
    }

private static IAsyncPolicy<HttpResponseMessage> GetCircuitBreakerPolicy()
{
    return HttpPolicyExtensions.HandleTransientHttpError()
        .CircuitBreakerAsync(3, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30), (result, retryAttempt) =>
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("circuit broken");
        },
        () =>
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("circuit closed");
        });
}

private static IAsyncPolicy<HttpResponseMessage> GetRetryPolicy()
{
    return HttpPolicyExtensions.HandleTransientHttpError()
        .Or<Exception>(e => !(e is BrokenCircuitException))
      .WaitAndRetryAsync(3,
          retryAttempt => TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500),
          onRetry: (context, attempt) =>
          {
              Debug.WriteLine("error");
          }
      );
}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `CircuitState` property is available on the `ICircuitBreaker` interface fulfilled by the policy instance:  (more in the Polly [readme](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly#circuit-breaker) and [wiki](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Circuit-Breaker#circuit-state-for-health-reporting-polly-v40))

```
CircuitState state = breaker.CircuitState;

/*
CircuitState.Closed
CircuitState.Open
CircuitState.HalfOpen
CircuitState.Isolated
*/
```

where `breaker` is the policy instance, ie the policy originally returned by your `GetCircuitBreakerPolicy()` method.

---

You could pass that circuit-breaker policy to the Controller via DI.  During startup you could do something like:

```
var breaker = GetCircuitBreakerPolicy();
services.AddSingleton<ICircuitBreakerPolicy<HttpResponseMessage>>(breaker as ICircuitBreakerPolicy<HttpResponseMessage>);
```

You'd need of course to use that [same single instance of `breaker`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59898047/) in the call to `.AddPolicyHandler(...)`, not manufacture a new/different one.

```
builder.AddPolicyHandler(GetRetryPolicy().WrapAsync(breaker));
```

The controller could then receive a copy of the breaker instance by constructor injection:

```
public class MyController
{
    public MyController(ICircuitBreakerPolicy<HttpResponseMessage> breaker, /* etc */)
    {
    }
}
```

---

Passing the circuit-breaker to the controller by registering `ICircuitBreakerPolicy<HttpResponseMessage>` on the DI container (as illustrated above) works well if the application is only using a single circuit-breaker instance.

If you have multiple circuit-breaker policy instances which need to be directly accessible elsewhere around the application, eg by controllers, store them in a [`PolicyRegistry`](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/PolicyRegistry), and pass the `IReadOnlyPolicyRegistry<string>` to the controller by DI.  There are [`.AddPolicyHandlerFromRegistry()` overloads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.pollyhttpclientbuilderextensions.addpolicyhandlerfromregistry) for configuring `HttpClient` with policies from a `PolicyRegistry`.

Answer (score 0):

The title of this question is general, without the constraint "without using a static variable". For others that do not have that constraint:

```
public class SomeHandler
{
    private static readonly Polly.CircuitBreaker.AsyncCircuitBreakerPolicy _circuitBreakerPolicy
        = Policy.Handle<Exception>().CircuitBreakerAsync(3, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2));

    public async Task Handle(IRequest request)
    {
        if (_circuitBreakerPolicy.CircuitState == Polly.CircuitBreaker.CircuitState.Open)
        {
            logger.LogInformation("The '_circuitBreakerPolicy' disallows SomeHandler to handle any requests now.");
            return;
        }
        var wrappedPolicy = Policy.WrapAsync(GetRetryPolicy(), _circuitBreakerPolicy);
        await wrappedPolicy.ExecuteAsync(...)
    }

    ...
}
```